# How to create nested Kibana query?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have a query like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": {
        "terms": {
          "appName": [
            "aaa", "bbb", "ccc"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'd like to use a sub query to dynamically generted the appName list like:

```
select distinct(appName) from Mytable where ...
```

Is it doable?

Comment: Can you add your ES mapping structure in the question? It's quite difficult to help you out with very less information.

Comment: if you want to select distinct you must use terms aggregate https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html